# Removing the ' from a list when indexing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-dataset

I have a list of numbers which I have in the following way (numbers are only an example):

```
list = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
```

I need them in an index format, so I do the following:

```
format = [list]
```

I now get it the following way:

```
['1, 2, 3, 4, 5']
```

However, I need it this way:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Can you tell me how to do that?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `list(ast.literal_eval('1, 2, 3, 4, 5'))` after `import ast`

Comment: `list = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'.split(',')`

Comment: `list(map(int, '1, 2, ...'.split(',')))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the split function this way:

```
list1 = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'

format1 = list(map(int, list1.split(', ')))

print(format1)
```

It will display :

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

PS : You should avoid having a variable called list. As it is a type of variable, it can cause serious issues

Comment: i got this error on this code : `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @user 1740557 That is because you assigned a string value to `list`. That masks the real `list`, which is why you should not do that.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is evaluate (`eval`) some code so it gets resolved by the interpreter. Since you cannot `eval` lists, you have to put the square brackets in the string, so it gets evaluated:

```
l = '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
eval(l)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Explanation:

Your first "list" is an object whose type is not a `list`, but a string (`str`).

```py
list = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
type(list)
>>> str
```

**By the way, I highly encourage you not to use python keywords such as 'list' as variable names**

When you put square brackets around, you're defining a list with a single object, which is this string object:

```py
format = [list]

type(format)
>>> list

len(format) # How many elements does it have?
>>> 1
```

So what you actually want to do is to define this list in a string manner and evaluate it:

```
l = '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
eval(l)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: this is not answer, input like this : '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' `not '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'`

Comment: @user1740577 The question looks formulated by someone who does not understand the basics of python, that's why I added the brackets to the string. I know it is not the input, but you can obviously add these with a simple function to the input, which I didn't add for simplicity

Comment: i know, i understand what you say, i say only that this not input and I say as you know i don't downvote you, i don't downvote any body